# Add Custom Attribute to Category to Select a CMS Page

Tags: attributes, eav

I'd like to be able to choose a CMS page with a custom attribute on a category. I know how to add a custom attribute to a category and have it be a select box, but is it possible to have the select populated with a list of CMS pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have preferred to have asked a comment but I don't have the reputation for that. However, to get you started, here is what you might want to try:

in your installer you can add in an attribute, something like this:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "cmspage",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "label"    => "CMS Page",
    "input"    => "select",
    "class"    => "",
    "source"   => "mymodule/eav_entity_attribute_source_cmspage",
    "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "user_defined"  => false,
    "default" => "",
    "searchable" => false,
    "filterable" => false,
    "comparable" => false,

    "visible_on_front"  => false,
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "CMS Page"
        ));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Then to get your cms pages to show you can then do something like this:

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Source_Cmspage extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {   $cmspages=Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
        $pages=array();
        foreach($cmspages as $scmspage) {
            $pages[$cmspage->getId()]=$cmspage->getTitle();
        }
        array_unshift($pages, array('label' => 'None', 'value' => ''));
        return($pages);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
        }
        return $_options;
    }
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option["value"] == $value) {
                return $option["label"];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note this is not tested, however, I hope it gets you along the way.

Comment: This looks awesome thx very much!